# SQL query to sum all open tickets for specific dates

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to count all open tickets for a specific date to create a graph showing sum how many open tickets required progressing at specific date. I have searched the forum, but only what I found was the number of opened tickets in a specific date and not a sum of open tickets for a specific date.

I have a table EBA_INTRACK_INCIDENTS with 2000 rows as below:

```
TICKET_ID                               CREATED                         DATE_CLOSED
217804114332145259901031334681504295360 22-APR-20 05.38.49.296025 AM    22-APR-20 10.36.06.632595 AM
217804143369593230815251434454955778995 22-APR-20 05.50.33.147871 AM    28-APR-20 08.58.39.042389 AM
217803008961875303185031769243177890561 22-APR-20 06.14.44.747808 AM    23-APR-20 05.51.15.455121 AM
217808140957154397731557630918372493817 22-APR-20 06.34.20.043731 AM    29-MAY-20 05.14.19.962409 AM
217809811756570636144585897003360863252 22-APR-20 08.36.02.343135 AM    30-APR-20 08.18.28.489497 PM
217837652922037663995843349384438376216 22-APR-20 01.21.11.767359 PM    22-APR-20 01.52.39.854154 PM
217837744730711438730249435800853415402 22-APR-20 01.22.27.709853 PM    22-APR-20 02.44.48.706025 PM
217839935479427184580816417746282266218 22-APR-20 01.56.45.960647 PM    22-APR-20 02.54.39.104983 PM
217906994241197252418147389816034708655 23-APR-20 05.17.09.562429 AM    27-APR-20 09.09.08.141999 AM
217907283724067577782873635569160329262 23-APR-20 05.21.09.020228 AM    23-APR-20 07.34.47.095888 AM
```

I think that to get the result I need query that will count tickets with criteria:

sum of (created < specific date and date_closed > specific date)
and this need to be done for all single dates.

I have tried the below, but this is not giving me the sum of open ticket for a specific date.

```
SELECT TRUNC(created) serie_label, sum (case when date_closed > created then 1 else 0 end) serie_value
FROM EBA_INTRACK_INCIDENTS i
WHERE TRUNC(created) IS NOT null and TRUNC(date_closed) IS NOT null
GROUP BY TRUNC(created)
ORDER BY TRUNC(created)


SERIE_LABEL SERIE_VALUE
04/22/2020  8
04/23/2020  53
04/24/2020  13
04/27/2020  5
04/28/2020  2
04/29/2020  3
04/30/2020  19
05/01/2020  14
05/04/2020  20
05/05/2020  21
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method is to unpivot the data so there is one date per rows and a flag.  Then use aggregation and cumulative sums to get the tickets open on a particular day:

```
with cc as (
      select trunc(created) as dte, 1 as inc
      from eba_intrack_incidents i
      where created is not null
      group by created
      union all
      select trunc(closed) as dte, -1 as inc
      from eba_intrack_incidents i
      where created is not null
      group by closed
     )
select dte, sum(inc) as change_on_day,
       sum(sum(inc)) over (order by dte) as open_on_day
from cc
group by dte;
```

Note:  This does not count the date when a ticket is closed.  If you want that, then add one day in the second subquery.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Thanks a lot.